# If Else Best Approach In Java

Tags: java

I am curious to know which programming style is better for If-else approach.
For e.g I want to iterate on for loop and want to execute action based on a input. I can do it in two ways:-
1)Iterate on for loop and put two break

```
for (Item item: items) {
            if(certainCondition()) {
                if (item.condition()) {//condition satisfied
                    executeIfLogic();
                    break;
                }
                executeElseLogic();
                break;
            }
```

}
        }
2)With If Else and a single break

```
for (Item item: items) {
            if(certainCondition()) {
                if (item.condition()) {//condition satisfied
                    executeIfLogic();
                }else{
                  executeElseLogic();
                 }
                break;
            }
        }
```

}
Sorry my fault. If Item satisfies upper certain condition, then only it will go to the inner if else. 
Which approach have to generally used and why?

Comment: why would you use a loop and then unconditionally break after the first iteration.

Comment: Neither approach is satisfactory. You're basing all your logic on properties of the first `item`. What is your intention here?

Comment: Generally I would say that the if-else is the better approach, since it gives a clearer meaning to the code.

Comment: Your approach is that you shouldn't even consider using a loop since the codes always only loop once. Also, this is an opinion based question even if your code makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break will leave the loop, so booth solutions will only 'iterate' over the first item.
The second solution without break would be right.
(Both solutions would work if you use continue instead of break)